# oracle listagg to return all records for certain values

Tags: oracle, listagg

I am trying to create an Oracle query that returns all groups and users for empno 1 & 2. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
emp table:  
 emp_no   
 ------  
   1    
   2   
        
group table:
 group_id  emp_no  
  --------  ----
    1          1
    1          2
    2          3
    2          4
    3          5
    3          6
            
-------------
  result
-------------
 group 1  empno 1, group 1 empno 2, group 2 empno 3, group 2 empno 4
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what error/unexpected result you obtained. Use CTE (with clause) rather than plaintext tables to specify your input data or prepare dbfiddle. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.

Comment: Also clarify specification: by `empno 1 & 2` you mean emps from the `emp` table? And why the group 2 is in the expected result when emps 1 and 2 belong only into group 1?

Comment: Do you have the `emp_no` and `group_id` columns reversed in the `group` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the group table is enough for your assignment.
The group table causes errors because of the name. I put it in double apostrophes (Oracle 11g R2).
You can use string functions in the `listagg` clause.
Even for `listagg`, you can get certain values using a where clause.   Multi-line results would use the group by clause, which is not the case.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  emp_no number
);

CREATE TABLE "group" (
  group_id number,
  emp_no number
);

insert into emp (emp_no) values (1);
insert into emp (emp_no) values (2);

insert into "group" (group_id,emp_no) values (1,1);
insert into "group" (group_id,emp_no) values (1,2);
insert into "group" (group_id,emp_no) values (2,3);
insert into "group" (group_id,emp_no) values (2,4);
insert into "group" (group_id,emp_no) values (3,5);
insert into "group" (group_id,emp_no) values (3,6);
```

Select:

```
select
listagg ('group ' || "group".group_id || ' empno ' || "group".emp_no, ', ')
  within group (order by "group".group_id, "group".emp_no) "result"
from "group"
where "group".group_id in (1,2);
```

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| group 1 empno 1, group 1 empno 2, group 2 empno 3, group 2 empno 4 |

Select corresponding to your assignment:

```
select
listagg ('group ' || "group".group_id || ' empno ' || "group".emp_no, ', ')
  within group (order by "group".group_id, "group".emp_no) "result"
from emp left join "group" on emp.emp_no="group".emp_no
where emp.emp_no in (1,2);
```

The output you have requested does not match:

| result |
| --- |
| group 1 empno 1, group 1 empno 2 |

---

### Edit 1:

As @MT0 have mentioned in the comment, for reversed columns `emp_no` and `group_id` in the `group` table there is a better result for the second select:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  emp_no number
);

CREATE TABLE "group" (
  group_id number,
  emp_no number
);

insert into emp (emp_no) values (1);
insert into emp (emp_no) values (2);

insert into "group" (emp_no,group_id) values (1,1);
insert into "group" (emp_no,group_id) values (1,2);
insert into "group" (emp_no,group_id) values (2,3);
insert into "group" (emp_no,group_id) values (2,4);
insert into "group" (emp_no,group_id) values (3,5);
insert into "group" (emp_no,group_id) values (3,6);
```

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| group 1 empno 1, group 2 empno 1, group 3 empno 2, group 4 empno 2 |

!!I messed the selection to reach the correct output:

```
select
listagg ('group ' || "group".emp_no || ' empno ' || "group".group_id, ', ')
  within group (order by "group".group_id, "group".emp_no) "result"
from emp left join "group" on emp.emp_no="group".emp_no
where emp.emp_no in (1,2);
```

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| group 1 empno 1, group 1 empno 2, group 2 empno 3, group 2 empno 4 |